# How do I build a Circut to create temperature changes in LEDs? Looking for a range of 3000 to 6,000 for photography?

Tags: led, light, circuit-design, light-sensor

I see commercial lights for photography that can change color in the range of 3-6,000 or tungsten to daylight values. These are not arrays of three RGB lights but rather single LEDs and the combination create fairly substantial light sources.

What options would I have for controlling those?

Comment: Are they single RGB LEDs?..each individual led contains three individual red,blue, and green LEDs. If so, you use PWM to control the intensity of the R G B leads individually to create any color you want.  Search for "PWM led drivers" Maybe include "high current" as well if you will have a lot of LEDS.

Comment: Maybe double up on the LEDs and mix cool white and warm white with various weightings.

Comment: http://www.sharpleds.com/tigerzenigata.html

Implementation of the current source for LEDs is not a trivial design task. Go search the internet for LED power supplies.

Comment: I've never seen an LED that would change wavelength without serious abuse. The "single LED"s are probably multiples in one package.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

They make LED strips in cool/warm white.  Electrically, they work exactly the same as RGB LED strips, except instead of 3 R-G-B elements, there are cool-warm ([and sometimes amber](https://onlinelightingrep.com/products/flexible-led-ribbon-strip-light-white-color-variable) to fill the third slot).  The strips come either [alternating LEDs](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=kFRqedSb1X4) or [both colors on the same LED die](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=RuZ9G1cn5yY) (like RGB LEDs).

You control them the same way as RGB strips, using PWM - blending between cool and warm white to suit.  they [even make controllers specifically for this task](https://www.superbrightleds.com/moreinfo/variable-white/variable-white-led-light-strips-kit-flexible-led-tape-light-with-36-smds-ft/1475/6657/).  For amplification or relaying, you can use common off-the-shelf 3-channel PWM dimmer amplifiers intended for RGB strips, just use 2 channels.

If you don't like the "strip" package, they make dual-emitter LEDs in other packages. You'd control them the same way you'd control a similar RGB LED.

Comment: Wouldn't a variable current source (steady LED output) be better than PWM (flickering LED output) *for photography*?

Comment: @peterj at full speed a DSLR shutter is just a thin slit, maybe just 1/10th of the frame, moving down the frame. This could detect a 50 kHz flicker. Unlikely you'd be using this speed under artificial light though.

Comment: Agreed, a variable-current source is ideal, but that means all LEDs must be fed in series from a current source. That is, a separate current source for each string -- which favors fewer, larger emitters and high voltages.  Controlling that digitally is harder which makes repeatability harder.   If multi-kilohertz PWM won't cut it, use an array with many segments and switch some on or off to suit.  Not infinitely variable, but steady.

Comment: Couldn't a largish capacitor be used to smooth out the flicker?  It's not like the OP is going to be changing the duty cycle dynamically -- he'll set a specific combination of cool and warm LEDs values and leave it there for the duration of the shot.

Comment: mmmmmmaybe...  The switching power supply may defeat the attempt by flowing even more current (to fill the capacitor) when it's on.

Comment: @tcrosley: A capacitor directly across an LED won't work well to smooth out the power flow to it, since the voltage across a cap will drop as energy is drawn from it, but even a small change in voltage will cause a big change in the current draw of an LED.

Comment: Yes.  Regulating voltage with PWM is obviously possible since switching power supplies do it... But there's more to it than a capacitor.   Anyway thanks to the resistor in every LED strip string, LED brightness will be proportional to voltage within a limited working range, but warm and cool strings may not be linear to each other.  That's why PWM is a win: the lamps are of predictable brightness when they're on.